# C - regarding the EOF function

Tags: c, file-io, matrix

I am trying to mess around with file input in C, mainly with integer values in a matrix format. For instance, if I have a file like...

```
4 5 7 3
6 8 5 2
5 7 3 4
9 4 8 7
```

I am confused as to what the EOF command will do. I know I can use it to check for end of file, but what if I wanted to test the end of a row? What if I wanted to print the diagonal right to left ( so 3,5,7,9 ). I know I would have to go row by row, set a counter that counts at each iteration to find the length of the rows, print out the last value of that row, then deduct the pointer by 1 and go onto the next row. But how can I do this? As in, is EOF only for the file as a whole, or is there a C command that can more directly define row lengths and such.

Comment: There is no `EOF` *command* or *function*. Do you mean [`feof()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/feof)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [read data from file till end of line in C/C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001907/read-data-from-file-till-end-of-line-in-c-c)

Comment: stdio.h defines `EOF` as a macro. It's the special value `-1` that some functions return to indicate end of file.

Comment: @guest Note: C defines `EOF` as "..., with type `int` and a negative value`", not necessarily `-1`.

Comment: end of a row : `'\n'`,

Answer (score 1):

A typical C program that reads multiple lines would look something like this:

```
char line[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), inputFile) != NULL)
{
    /* Do something with line */
}
```

The part that says "Do something with line" is where you should do something. One thing to do in your case would be to parse the line, and get one of the numbers in it. Which one would depend on the line number (which you have to keep track of your self), so the first number for the first line, the second number for the second line, etc. Then when you have all numbers (i.e. when the loop ends) you do what you want with the data.

After the loop ends, you can use [`feof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/feof) or [`ferror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ferror) to see if it ended because of end-of-file or an error.

Answer (score 0):

When scanning through a file, you can separate the file into lines by splitting the file on the `\n` token. This is a newline and is present at the end of every line. Also, you can split on the `\t` token. This represents a tab.

Comment: Or a space, which is represented by a space. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_DIGIT_OFLINE 10
#define EOR '\n' //END OF ROW

int main(){
    char digits[MAX_DIGIT_OFLINE];
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("data.txt", "r");
    int n=0,last=-1;

    for(;;){
        int ch = fgetc(fp);
        if(isdigit(ch)){
            digits[n++] = ch;
        } else if(ch == EOR || ch == EOF){
            last = (last==-1) ? n -1: last -1;
            putchar(digits[last]);
            if(ch == EOF) break;
            n = 0;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    putchar(EOR);

    return 0;
}
```